# GAM: smooth interaction with factor that depends on second factor

Tags: interaction, generalized-additive-model

I have the following scenario I'm trying to model with `mgcv::gam`. I have a continuous explanatory variable X whose response depends on factor A. However, That X*A interaction may also depend on factor B for some, but possibly not all factor levels of A. X however is not expected to separately depend on only B. Without factor B it's straightforward as

`mod<-gam(Y ~ s(X, by=A), data=dat, method='REML'`

but I don't know how to incorporate that X * A * B interaction into this model. I don't think just adding a `+ A*B` after the smooth term is the correct approach, as I'm trying to model the response of Y specifically to X, not to A/B. Would I need to include B as a random effect? I'm not very familiar with mixed models, so any help is appreciated. A and B have different lengths.

Comment: The accepted answer to this Q might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68659805/8234333